# Same Server, Change just website address

Tags: domain

I'm considering to change our store website address

**Is there any link or info I should check before/while changing address?**

I don't move server. Server is same. I just want change my domain address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only change the secure_base_url and the unsecure_base_url. That might do the trick and can be achieved with a raw SQL query or via the Magento Admin. [Here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/restore_base_url_settings) you can see the documentation for this.

Comment: Is it okay and done just change 'secure_base_url and the unsecure_base_url'? So there is nothing other I have to do?

Comment: There is nothing else to do regarding Magento.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly point your new domain to the magento directory
by using DocumentRoot in your vhost file.

You have to update the secure and unsecure url in core_config_data table:

Like this :

```
web/unsecure/base_url value to http://yournewdomainname.com/
web/secure/base_url value to https://yournewdomainname.com/
```

Cheers